# How do I serialize an ImageField in Django?

Tags: python, django, json, serialization, django-models

I'm trying to serialize one of my models  which has an `ImageField`. The inbuilt serializer can't seem to serialize this and therefore I thought of writing a custom serializer. Could you tell me how I could serialize an image and use this with the default JSON serializer in Django?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote an extension to the simplejson encoder. Instead to serializing the image to base643, it returns the path of the image. Here's a snippet:

```
def encode_datetime(obj):
    """
    Extended encoder function that helps to serialize dates and images
    """
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
        try:
            return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        except ValueError, e:
            return ''

    if isinstance(obj, ImageFieldFile):
        try:
            return obj.path
        except ValueError, e:
            return ''

    raise TypeError(repr(obj) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I must admit - not to serialize `ImageFieldFile` out of the box is rather... ridiculous of Django.

Answer (score 6):

you can't serialize the object, because it's an Image. You have to serialize the string representation of it's path.

The easiest way of achiving it is to call it's str() method when you what to serialize it.

```
json.dumps(unicode(my_imagefield)) # py2
json.dumps(str(my_imagefield)) # py3
```

should work.

Comment: This answer could be very useful if given more context, especially for Django newbies. For example, where should that code go?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [base64 encoding](http://effbot.org/librarybook/base64.htm) in order to serialize the image to be used inside a JSON

Answer (score 1):

Use another encoder such that:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile


class ExtendedEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ImageFieldFile):
            return str(o)
        else:
            return super().default(o)


result = json.dumps(your_object, cls=ExtendedEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the ContentFile class that handles the binary data into a temporary file so serializer can deal with it till it pass it to the model, the your model will store that actual image with the given name in the media root and database will store the path only and I hope the example that I will write below will help.

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import requests
#local imports
from .serializers import ImageSerializer


class ImageCreateAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            url = serializer.validated_data['url']
            response = requests.get(url).content
            image = ContentFile(response, name=url.split('/')[-1])
            serializer.validated_data['image'] = image
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```