# Overriding Google-Auth user creation

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, google-oauth

[image]

[image]

I added the google login and when I selected an account  after the continue I get the following.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\utils.py", line 229, in deserialize_instance
    v = f.from_db_value(v, None, None)

During handling of the above exception ('ImageField' object has no attribute 'from_db_value'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\views.py", line 39, in dispatch
    self.sociallogin = SocialLogin.deserialize(data)
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\models.py", line 215, in deserialize
    user = deserialize_instance(get_user_model(), data["user"])
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\adapter.py", line 189, in deserialize_instance
    return deserialize_instance(model, data)
  File "C:\Users\arund\Desktop\Code\Django\portfolio-project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\utils.py", line 231, in deserialize_instance
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/social/signup/
Exception Value: Unable to auto serialize field 'verified', custom serialization override required
```

**I have an abstractuser with the field verified and want to create a default user with google all-auth. How would I handle that? It says I need to serialize verified and avatar the only two imagefields.**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.templatetags.static import static

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=25, region='US')
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True) 
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verified = models.ImageField(default='',upload_to='media/doctor')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/avatars',null=True)

    gender_choices = (('others', 'Others'),('male', 'Male'),('female' ,'Female'))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=gender_choices,default='others')
    default_pic_mapping = { 'others': 'default.png', 'male': 'default.png', 'female': 'default.png'}

    def get_profile_pic_url(self):
        if not self.avatar:
            return static('img/{}'.format(self.default_pic_mapping[self.gender]))
        return self.avatar.url
```

Comment: I don't think you can serialize an ImageField.  Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497138/how-do-i-serialize-an-imagefield-in-django.

Comment: I would like to override it.

Comment: Honestly, this is out of my league.  I refer you back to my link, or hopefully someone with more knowledge than me can help.

Comment: I swapped over to python social auth which worked now I'm trying to add access keys to calendar and then use their calendar.

Comment: you need to provide a code that generates this exception 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Create the Custom User Model in models.py***

You can use the Django example, or follow with ours below. We will simplify the process here.

accounts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser

    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Email & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin
```

***Update settings module (aka settings.py):***

### 1. Run Migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

2. Update settings.py

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

3. Run Migrations again

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

4. Create a superuser

```
    python manage.py createsuperuser
```

5. Some practical thoughts

Setting the AUTH_USER_MODEL means that we can use many third party packages that leverage the Django user model; packages like Django Rest Framework, Django AllAuth, Python Social Auth, come to mind.

Now, every time you need the user model, use:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
```

This provides other developers and our future selves the kind of peace of mind that only well-thought-out code can provide; get_user_model is one of those pieces the core Django developers decided on long ago.

6 But what about User foreign keys? At some point you'll be faced with this situation:

```
    class SomeModel(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

So what to use? get_user_model accounts.models.User or what? Actually, you'll use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL every time regardless of user model customization. So it will look like this:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    
    class SomeModel(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### hope this answers your question... ?